# Search for keywords in array and only get the matching elements in MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection asset and This is my Data

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e71d235a3b5401685a058"),
  "company" : ObjectId("5e6b834b5991d70945840"),
  "asset_name" : "LG-OLED-55-Inch",
  "installedAt" : ["lobby", "storeroom", "f105"],
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e71d235a3b540168475d8"),
  "company" : ObjectId("5e6b834b5991d70945840"),
  "asset_name" : "LG-OLED-32-Inch",
  "installedAt" : ["lobby", "f108"],
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eb3d53a7e16dc70244d6578"),
 "company" : ObjectId("5e6b834b5991d70945840"),
  "asset_name" : "LG-OLED-68-Inch",
  "installedAt" : ["tvroom", "f105"],
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eb3d53a7e16dc7024474a12"),
 "company" : ObjectId("5e6b834b5991d70945840"),
  "asset_name" : "LG-OLED-22-Inch",
  "installedAt" : ["tvroom"],
}
```

So for the above data my requirement is to search for keyword in `installedAt` and return all the elements that match the keyword which user provides.

For Example, if the user searches for `f10` then we should search all the `installedAt` arrays in `assests` and return like below

```
"installedAt": ["f105","f108"]
```

And I have tried using `$in` for getting similar elements but it is not working as I have expected.
This is my query

```
 var autoRecords =[];
    key = [searchString];        
    key.forEach(function(opt){
        autoRecords.push(new RegExp(opt,"i"));                
    }); 

Assets.find({ "installedAt" : {"$in" : autoRecords},"company": companyId},{"installedAt" : 1})
```

So for the above query when I try to send search text which is `f10` the result is as below

```
[
{"installedAt":["lobby", "storeroom", "f105"],"_id":"5e71d235a3b5401685a058"},
{"installedAt":["lobby", "f108"],"_id":"5e71d235a3b540168475d8"},
{"installedAt":["tvroom", "f105"],"_id":"5eb3d53a7e16dc70244d6578"},
]
```

It is getting all elements in the `installedAt` array even if it finds one. So Can anyone help me in getting only matched elements in the array and try to obtain this format

```
"installedAt": ["f105","f108"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
const data = await Assets.aggregate([
  { $match: { installedAt: { $regex: "f10", $options: "i" }}},
  { $unwind: "$installedAt" },
  { $match: { installedAt: { $regex: "f10", $options: "i" }}},
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    data: { $addToSet: "$installedAt" }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pd0Wb4WigQM)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's working as expected.